# Get array of selected dates from availability calendar

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have this availability calendar where multiple dates can be selected. so far I am able to get value of individual cell but not the array of values of total cells selected.

```js
$('td').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
var tbl = document.getElementById("calender-table");
 if (tbl != null) {
 for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
 tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () { getval(this); };
            }
        }
 function getval(cel) {
  alert(cel.innerHTML);
 }
```

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="calender-table" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need some assistance on how to get array of theses multiple selected dates and get as an array so that I can insert them to db using PHP/MySql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save you selected value in an array as `selected.push(getval(this)` Remove element if class active is not present;

```js
$('td').click(function() {
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
var selected = [];
var tbl = document.getElementById("calender-table");
 if (tbl != null) {
 for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 0; j < tbl.rows[i].cells.length; j++)
 tbl.rows[i].cells[j].onclick = function () {
   var item = getval(this);
   if($(this).hasClass('active')){ 
   selected.push(item);
           } else {
             var index = selected.indexOf(item);
             selected.splice(index, 1);
           }                                 console.log(selected);}
   
  
   
            }
        }
 function getval(cel) {
  return cel.innerHTML;
  alert(cel.innerHTML);
 }
```

```css
td {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table align="center" id="calender-table" border="1" style="cursor: pointer;">
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
<tr><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this will not work, if you deselect one, it would not pop the item from the list

Comment: @shubham... Thanks... would it dis-select the value if clicked twice on a date?

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner yes

Comment: @Shubham Khatri, looking for some suggestion if a hidden div can be displayed if one or more dates are selected and hide if no dates are selected or after dis-selecteing all dates.. thanks in advance.

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner when you have an array you can repace add class to the div if array has elements that displays it and hide if it doesnt
use selected.length to find its size

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, How can I use `selected.push(getval(this))` as you have mentioned above, to save the array of values selected? I am sorry, struggling for 2 days.

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner make use of  localstorage to save the array or you can make use of cookies but local storage is aa better option. You can Google for localstorage with JavaScript

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri, when I replaced `console.log(selected);` by `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = selected;`, I can see the array on my html. Is there a way to convert it to PHP variable without being jquery array saved?

Comment: @CodeIgniter_Learner I am sorry I havent use php at all, I cant help you with it. It would be good if you ask another question on SO regarding this issue or loop for ajax call to send your data to backend php file.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to echo array in hidden "input" field for MySql submission by `document.getElementById("dates").value = selected;`.. Working perfect now.